# Remove other's Plugin Meta Box from my Custom Plugin

Tags: wordpress, plugins, meta-boxes

I have an issue i created a WordPress plugin which included a meta-box but when i included yoast and revolution slider plugin with my plugin their's plugin's meta box will conflict with my meta box.
I want to remove all other's meta-box except mine How would i do that. 
I have been searching i think

```
global $wp_meta_boxes;
```

helps me out but how ?

Comment: What kind of conflict?

Comment: Revolution slider and Yoast SEO plugin's Meta-Box comes up with my plugin Meta-Box 
I don't want that.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=remove_meta_box